# How does the following code mean two consecutive numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is from an exercise on FCC beta and i can not understand how the following code means two consecutive numbers seeing how `\D*` means NOT 0 or more numbers and `\d` means number, so how does this accumulate to two numbers in a regexp?

```
let checkPass = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d)/;
```

Comment: You are not matching anything. The regex you have has simply defined [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - these do no matching and will effectively match an empty string when the lookaheads are satisfied.

Comment: in the example - when you say `(` followed by `?` , are you using `?` as a regex syntax or do you mean '\?' coz its followed by `(` and i dont see how it works for you?

Comment: @AnkushRathi The `?=` is a positive lookahead that is for the exercise where i am creating a regex to be used to check a pw

Comment: Two consecutive numbers would simply be something like `(\d)(\d)` or `(\d{1})(\d{1})`. Your regex basically matches an empty string, as smac89 says. Where exactly did you find this? Where does it say it should match two digits?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley https://beta.freecodecamp.org/en/challenges/regular-expressions/positive-and-negative-lookahead

Comment: I see. I've left an answer below. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: i always recommend [regexr](https://regexr.com/) for reg expression issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not match two numbers. It doesn't really match anything except an empty string, as there is nothing preceding the lookup.

If you want to match two digits, you can do something like this:

```
(\d)(\d)
```

Or if you really want to do a positive lookup with the `(?=\D*\d)` section, you will have to do something like this:

```
\d(?=\D*\d)
```

This will match against the last digit which is followed by a bunch of non-digits and a single digit. A few examples (matched numbers highlighted):

```
2 hhebuehi3
^
245673
^^^^^
2v jugn45
^      ^
```

To also capture the second digit, you will have to put brackets around both numbers. Ie:

```
(\d)(?=\D*(\d))
```

[Here it is in action](https://regex101.com/r/Ec3xlJ/1).

In order to do what your original example wants, ie:

- number
- 5+ `\w` characters
- a non-number character
- a number

... you will need to precede your original example with a `\d` character. This means that your lookups will actually match something which isn't just an empty string:

```
\d(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d)
```

---

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

After playing around a bit more with a JavaScript online console, I have worked out the problem with your original Regex.

This matches a string with 5 or more characters, including at least 1 number. This *can* match two numbers, but it can also match 1 number, 3 numbers, 12 numbers, etc. In order to match exactly two numbers in a string of 5-or-more characters, you should specify the number of digits you want in the second half of your lookup:

```
let regex = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d{2})/;
```

```js
let string1 = "abcd2";
let regex1 = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d)/;
console.log("string 1 & regex 1: " + regex1.test(string1));

let regex2 = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d{2})/;
console.log("string 1 & regex 2: " + regex2.test(string1));

let string2 = "abcd23";
console.log("string 2 & regex 2: " + regex2.test(string2));
```

My original answer was about Regex in a vacuum and I glossed over the fact that you were using Regex in conjunction with JavaScript, which works a little differently when comparing Regex to a string. I still don't know why your original answer was supposed to match two numbers, but I hope this is a bit more helpful.

Comment: So im still curious how (?=\D*\d) means one or more numbers when (?=\d+) would be it in my mind? What is the point of the \D*?

Comment: The two lookaheads are used in conjunction with one another. Isolated, that one doesn’t really make much sense but together `(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d)` seems to mean “any string of letters or numbers which is 5 characters or more in length and contains at least one occurrence of *zero or more non-numbers followed by a number*”. Seems a little redundant but whatever... I guess it would be helpful if you wanted to capture the stuff before the number as well as the number itself. Depends what you’re using the regex for I guess

Comment: @ajhernandez95 why did you unaccept my answer and accept another one nearly four months after accepting this one?

Comment: I was going trough past questions and making sure I chose the right answer rather than the first but after reviewing your answer yours is clearly more detailed and thorough sorry about that.

Comment: Not to worry, I was only curious :-) I appreciate you re-accepting my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

`?=` Positive lookahead
`w{5,}` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
`{5,}.` matches between 5 and unlimited
`\D*` matches any character that\'s not a digit (equal to [^0-9])
`*` matches between zero and unlimited
`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

This expression is global - so tries to match all

You can always check your expression using [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: you may want to put this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I understand what each part does i just dont understand how (?=\D*\d) means two consecutive numbers here.